# Angular error this.mymethod is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an image slider inside my Angular 5 component. The slider has Previous and Next controls which both work fine but I can't get it to slide automatically.

```
<!-- language: lang-typescript -->
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
@Component({...})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  private slides;
  private dots;
  private slideIndex: any = 1
  private len;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    /* Gets a nodelist of the slider images in the DOM */
    this.slides = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    /* The control dots at the bottom of the slider */
    this.dots = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".slider__dots > *")
    this.len = this.slides.length

    this.showImage(this.slideIndex)
    this.autoslide() /* Errors out with the message "this.imageCycle is not a function" */
  }

  /* The main slider method */
  showImage(n) {

    if (n > this.len) { this.slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { this.slideIndex = this.len }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.len; i++) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.slides[i], 'display', 'none')
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.dots[i], 'active-dot')
    }

    this.renderer.addClass(this.slides[this.slideIndex-1], 'fade')
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.slides[this.slideIndex-1], 'display', 'block')
    this.renderer.addClass(this.dots[this.slideIndex-1], "active-dot")
  }


  /* Cycles through the images, either previous or next */
  imageCycle(n) {
    this.showImage(this.slideIndex += n)
  }

  /* Handles the dots */
  currentImage(n) {
    this.showImage(this.slideIndex = n)
  }

  /* Automatically slide through the images */
  autoslide() {
    this.imageCycle(1)
    setTimeout(this.autoslide, 2000)
  }
}
```

My Next and Previous buttons both call the imageCycle() method passing in 1 for next and -1 for previous as the parameters. Both these buttons work fine. However, I would also like for the slider to slide automatically hence the autoslide method but upon calling it, it errors out with the message "TypeError: this.imageCycle is not a function".
What am I doing wrong? I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
setTimeout(this.autoslide, 2000)
```

to

```
setTimeout(this.autoslide.bind(this), 2000)
```

for `this` to keep pointing to the current class instance.

Comment: Wow that was fast and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call `setTimeout` you pass the function without binding it to the current `this`. In Javascript `this` is determined by the caller for functions. You can capture `this` from the declaration context by using arrow functions or `bind`:

```
setTimeout(this.autoslide.bind(this), 2000)
// OR
setTimeout(()=> this.autoslide(), 2000)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I should probably revisit my basic javascript. I keep getting tripped up by the 'this' keyword.